# Syncthing-capable BSD router for max. 100 EUR/120 USD

Tags: router, server, access-point, firewall

This is a simplified model of our network:

```
LAN1                                           LAN2
+-------------------------------+              +--------------------------+
|                               |              |                          |
| +---+  eth  +----+   wl  +--+ |  +--------+  | +---+  eth  +----------+ |
| |NAS+-------+RASP+-------+AP+----+INTERNET+----+DSL+-------+OPENWRT/AP| |
| +---+       +----+       +--+ |  +--------+  | +---+       +----------+ |
|                               |              |                          |
+-------------------------------+              +--------------------------+
```

LAN1 and LAN2 are currently completely separated (no VPN, ssh, etc.), each running **Syncthing** within their realm. I would be very grateful, if you can give me recommendations for replacing the following units:

1. **Raspberry Pi**: Runs Syncthing and serves the NAS files to LAN1. It needs to be replaced with something more reliable.
2. **OpenWRT/AP**: This is a blue Linksys with OpenWRT, an early model with not enough disk space. It is not running Syncthing.

Ideally, they should be replaced by 2 units of the **same model**.

---

#### Criteria

The criteria for the new units replacing the OpenWRT/AP and Raspberry Pi are:

- Must: Reliable (max. 1h/week downtime, i.e. approx. 99% uptime)
- Must: Has Ethernet and WiFi
- Must: No SD card as storage
- Must: Able to run Syncthing
- Must: Able to run FreeBSD or OpenBSD
- Must: Costs max. 100 EUR/120 USD per device
- Optional: Max. horizontal size 14 x 11 cm, height variable

---

#### Researched Solutions

- Ubiquiti airRouter: Has PoE, can be used as a client, but can't host Syncthing
- PC Engines Alix/APU boards: Good for BSD, but too expensive
- GL.iNet AR150: Good size, but runs OpenWRT
- Ubiquiti EdgeRouter Lite: Does not have WiFi